# GCC флаг -no-pie

Tags: c++, c, gcc, x86, x86-64

Что означает фалг gcc -no-pie.

Comment: ответ «слинковать не-pie бинарник» устроит?

Comment: [Дубликат на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47778099/3240681)

Comment: `-fpie` -- это  флаг линкера -- сформировать *"a position independent executable on targets which support it"*.  Соответственно, `no-pie`  не требует делать такое. Можно также почитать [man gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)